# Запрос и вывод данных в шаблон

Tags: python, django

Есть такие две модели.

```
class Banner(models.Model):
bannerid = models.IntegerField()
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class BannerPhrases(models.Model):
banner = models.ForeignKey(Banner)
phrase = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Как мне сделать, чтоб окончательный вид был такой, как на картинке.

[image: img]

У меня только получается вывести по каждой фразе свой `title` и `bannerid`, т.е. если 4 фразы, то и будет 4 баннера, а мне надо, один баннер и к нему 4 фразы.

Comment: А подробней можно? просто сведений маловато.